# Search a string of text occuring anywhere in value of all the fields of elastic index?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i have a wildcard or a string of text say for example "abc" i want to search the occurence of this text anywhere in the value of a field but i want to search this in all the fields of a document is this possible using a wildcard query? also how to write the query using the java query builder objects

if i use the following how to write it using java

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*roj*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ofk possible by mapping all fields using elasticsearch **should**(OR) statement, but this is a pain you know where and not really performant from elasticsearch side.

I would highly recommend to use **copy_to** approach.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

[image]

You will have to modify your index, and make reindexing of existing data, but after that - every field you have - will be additionally added to aggregated field and you will be able to search only in 1 field.

This is a pretty common approach in most search engines. Copying all keywords to 1 field, and allowing to make something like single line google search panel which will **search within all keywords**.